# How can I enable shutter release without a lens on a Canon EOS M3?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, shutter, shutter-release, canon-m

I'm trying to use a reverse lens adapter for macro pics, but the shutter does not work. I understand the pins are not in contact. I have heard there is an option in the menu to release the shutter without a lens being properly mounted. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Photography.SE! I submitted an edit to remove your email address and clean up your formatting.  The way things work here is that we share answers publicly; soliciting them to your email address is not accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do it. Open the menu and go to the C.Fn tab. Look for "Release shutter w/o lens" and set it to "Enable". Detailed in [the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0300017917/02/eosm3-cu2-en.pdf) on page 186.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted then.

Comment: Note that the C.Fn tab only shows up when the camera is in the C1, C2, M, P, A or T modus